# Notepad ++ Find word and replace line above and below

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

Here's my example :

```
class Item478
{
    position[]={14186.376,18.035046,18340.531};
    azimut=-134.41499;
    id=734;
    side="EMPTY";
    vehicle="Land_LampStreet_F";
    skill=0.60000002;
    init="this enableSimulation true; this allowDamage false;";
};
```

I have multiple paragraphs. I need to find the word "Land_LampSreet_F and delete the line above and below.
How can I use regular expression or extended mode of Find & replace ?

Answer (score 1):

Macro allows you to repeat a set of actions again (and again...) but you will need to "teach" Notepad++ what it is you want to do first. So follow the instructions below closely or you could end up with a non-working result.

Please note that for simplicity I will only explain how to work with macros for your first case (your first file) so as not to repeat myself unnecessarily. Also, please make sure you have a backup copy of the original file before you attempt this in case something does not work as intended.

Okay, here goes:

Open up Notepad++, open up your file.

Make sure you are at the beginning of your first line of data, that is, the first line with the first word in your dictionary in your case.

From the "Macro" menu select "Start recording"

Do what you need to do with only the first set of data. The last step here is important because you want to be at the 'right place' for the next run-through of your macro

Now from the "Macro" menu select "Stop recording"

From the "Macro" menu, select "Save the recorded macro", and give it some appropriate name and click "OK"

Now (still having the cursor at the beginning of next line) select "Macro" > "Run a macro multiple times", select the macro you saved in step 6 and choose "Run to end of file", then click OK.

The macro will now work its way through your file. Be sure to give it a moment to finish if your file is large! You should now see that the macro has moved all your lines down as needed.

The same principle can be applied to your second request, although that requires a more advanced macro with more recorded actions. Once you understand the concept and know how to record a macro and play it back, however, it should be doable.

Hope this was helpful!